# What is better to choose for public and private chats on the site: IRC or Jabber?

Tags: chat, xmpp, irc, instant-messaging

I am looking for a solution to implement a public chat and a system of instant messaging within the site.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer irc i think its easier to understand for my visitors...

Answer (score 0):

although I prefer irc... I think it depends on the type of users on your site. I think for most jabber is better. Meebo allows you to embed their jabber chat on your site. I think that's a good thing ;) you should check out that.